# Tracing two paths at the same time on an HTML5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, optimization

I have code that is spiritually equivalent to this snippet:

```
function drawComplicatedThing(ctx) {
    let [px, py] = [0, 0];
    for (let i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
        let {x, y} = computeExpensive(i);

        // black along
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(px, py);
        ctx.lineTo(x, y);
        ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
        ctx.stroke();

        // red transpose
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(py, px);
        ctx.lineTo(y, x);
        ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';
        ctx.stroke();

        [px, py] = [x, y];
    }
}
```

I'm trying to optimize the code by batching the calls to stroke. For example, I could do this:

```
function drawComplicatedThing(ctx) {
    // black along
    ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
    for (let i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
        let {x, y} = computeExpensive(i);
        ctx.lineTo(x, y);
    }
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
    ctx.stroke();

    // red transpose
    ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
    for (let i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
        let {x, y} = computeExpensive(i);
        ctx.lineTo(y, x);
    }
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';
    ctx.stroke();
}
```

But notice that now I'm calling `computeExpensive` twice as many times. This is slower, but the real cost is that in practice `computeExpensive` is actually an inline block of code, so our optimization has forced gross code duplication.

Restructuring the example code to avoid the code duplication is easy (just cache the points into an array), but in general there may be conditional drawing logic and that's a lot harder to restructure away when duplicated.

It would be easy to workaround this issue if I could trace two paths at the same time. Something like this:

```
function drawComplicatedThing(ctx) {
    let ctx2 = ctx.independentCopy(); // <-- NOT REAL, but you get the idea
    ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
    ctx2.moveTo(0, 0);
    for (let i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
        let {x, y} = computeExpensive(i);
        ctx.lineTo(x, y);
        ctx2.lineTo(y, x);
    }
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx2.strokeStyle = 'red';
    ctx2.stroke();
}
```

Does this kind of functionality exist in HTML5, or am I required to structure my code around only being able to trace one path-to-stroke at a time?

Comment: You _could_ try calling a second `getContext`, but even if it works it might be clearer to just store the points to render into an array and then pass it twice.

Comment: @JanDvorak. There is only 1 context per canvas so multiple `getContext` calls always get the same one-and-only context. Your suggestion of caching the expensively obtained points sounds like the right answer. :-)

Comment: I suspect JanDvorak has your answer, but you could always use two canvases (one for black lines, one for red lines) and combine them with: `blackContext.drawImage(redCanvas,0,0)`.

Comment: @JanDvorak I did actually try that before asking. The two results are `===` to each other, so it's just referring to the same context.

Comment: @markE You don't even need to combine them if you put them on top of each other (interesting idea by the way; I may try that out myself)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a path to draw on independently of the canvas context.

```js
const pathBlack = new Path2D()
const pathRed = new Path2D()
pathBlack.moveTo(0, 0);
pathRed.moveTo(0, 0);

for (let i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
    let {x, y} = computeExpensive(i);
    pathBlack.lineTo(x, y);
    pathRed.lineTo(y, x);
}

ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
ctx.stroke(pathBlack);
ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';
ctx.stroke(pathRed);
```